# javascriptで、配列内の文字を改行したいです。

Tags: javascript, html5

以下のJavaScriptのプログラムがあります。

これは、1問目と2問目をそれぞれ松山市と高松市と入力すれば50と出力されるようなプログラムになっています。
さらに、そこに加えて、それとは別に配列が用意され、50の場合には「あいうえお」と出力されるようなプログラムになっています。

ところが、例えば仮に「あいう」と「えお」という風に改行することができません。
もとから配列はそのような挙動は不可能なのでしょうか。
配列でも文章内改行が可能であればそれを使いたいのですが…。

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function kotae() {
    ten = 0
    if (
        (f.q1.value == "松山市" && f.q2.value == "高松市") || 
        (f.q1.value == "高松市" && f.q2.value == "松山市")) { 
            f.q1.style.backgroundColor = "aqua "
            ten = ten + 50 
    } else {
        f.q1.style.backgroundColor = "red"
    }

    if (f.q3.value == "名古屋市") { 
        f.q3.style.backgroundColor = "aqua " 
        ten = ten + 25 
    } else { 
        f.q3.style.backgroundColor = "red"
    }
    
    if (f.q4.value == "金沢市") { 
        f.q4.style.backgroundColor = "aqua " 
        ten = ten + 25 
    } else {
        f.q4.style.backgroundColor = "red"
        f.tokuten.value = ten
    }

    const keywords = ['あいうえお', 'かきくけこ', 'さしすせそ']
    if (f.tokuten.value = 50) {
        for (let i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
            console.log(f.rank.value = keywords[0])
        }
    } else if (f.tokuten.value >= 20) {
        f.rank.value = 'B'
    } else if (f.tokuten.value >= 15) {
        f.rank.value = 'C'
    } else if (f.tokuten.value < 10) {
        f.rank.value = 'D'
    }
    //ここまで
  }
</script>
```

Comment: 「ところが、例えば仮にあいうとえおという風に開業することができません。」とはもう少しやりたいことが伝わるように説明いただけないでしょうか？どういう入力を想定されているのでしょうか？

Comment: 表示の際に `<br />` タグを使えばよさそうな気もしますが、そういう事ではないのでしょうか？

Comment: cubickさんによる編集でJavaScriptコードに余計なものが混入していたため、ロールバックしました。

Comment: int32_t さん 自分の編集では (コード部分は) コードフェンスで囲っただけなので、「余計なもの」については質問者本人による [編集](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/revisions/89767/2) で付け加えたものかと思われます。

Comment: コード中の f.rank が何なのか質問文からは読み取れないので回答がつかないのでしょう。

Answer (score 0):

以下の様に記述したらどうですか？

```
const keywords = ['あいう\nえお', 'かきくけこ', 'さしすせそ']
```